# How to get a data frame from sapply function?

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply, rbind

I am using `sapply()` to generate 30 random walk simmmulations with a function of my own called `levy.walk.flights()`.

```
simmulations=30
granMAT <- sapply(1:simmulations, function(i){
   a <- levy.walk.flights()[[1]]
   cbind(a,rep(i, length(a[,1])))
})
```

The object `a` receives a `data.frame` with 2 columns: x, y; plus an ID column that is cbinded in the next line of code.

This code works perfectly and produces all 30 simmulations. The only problem is that the `sapply()` returns a list of 30*3 (90) arrays. See an example of the `str(granMAT)` with 3 simmulations.

```
List of 9
$ : num [1:5748] 0 0.00357 0.0074 0.01071 0.01418 ...
$ : num [1:5748] 0 0.135 0.28 0.406 0.537 ...
$ : int [1:5748] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ : num [1:2434] 0 -0.131 -0.261 -0.385 -0.527 ...
$ : num [1:2434] 0 -0.048 -0.0955 -0.1412 -0.1933 ...
$ : int [1:2434] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ : num [1:2301] 0 -0.0887 -0.1829 -0.276 -0.364 ...
$ : num [1:2301] 0 0.0941 0.1939 0.2927 0.386 ...
$ : int [1:2301] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
- attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 3 3
- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
..$ : chr [1:3] "x" "y" "rep(i, length(a[, 1]))"
..$ : NULL`
```

I would like the `sapply()` to return a `data.frame`with 3 columns: x, y, ID. And all data rbinded below these 3 columns. I have tried `do.call()` and several `library(plyr)` functions but I can't figure out which function would allow me to do this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You'll never get `sapply` to return a data frame unless you rewrite it.  It returns either a list or a matrix or an atomic vector, depending on whether the result is to be simplified. Try `lapply`

Comment: Using @RichardScriven's advice by doing something like `ret <- lapply(1:sims, function(i) { ... })`, it should work to follow that with `granMat <- do.call(rbind, ret)`. This assumes all data.frames have the same column names (which it appears they do), otherwise you'll need more tricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
simmulations=30
granMAT <- sapply(1:simmulations, function(i){
   a <- levy.walk.flights()[[1]]
   cbind(a,rep(i, length(a[,1])))
}) %>% rbind_all
```

`rbind_all` is a short-hand function from dplyr equal to do.call("rbind", list). Piping your results from the sapply into rbind_all, means it will take the list and bind all the rows together, returning a data.frame.